# header code 302 beforer the 404 requested

Tags: .htaccess, seo, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-302

I have a .htaccess file with several redirect rules and also this line :
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mapaetmoi.fr/404.php

However when I type a url that does not exist such as https://www.mapaetmoi.fr/test/error, and I analyze the header, I have this:
URL: https://www.mapaetmoi.fr/test/error

HTTP / 1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 28 Jul 2021 14:25:28 GMT
Content-Type: text / html; charset = iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.mapaetmoi.fr/404.php

HTTP / 1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 28 Jul 2021 14:25:28 GMT
Content-Type: text / html; charset = UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP / 7.3
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID = a10d873a06024ca42cf32d4ac4ae87ea; path = /; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID = a10d873a06024ca42cf32d4ac4ae87ea; expires = Fri, 27-Aug-2021 14:25:28 GMT; Max-Age = 2592000; path = /; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite = Strict

So it looks like there is a 302 redirect to my 404.php page which does return the 404 code

For SEO, I would like it to return code 404 directly. So I must have done something wrong but I can't seem to find ...

An idea ? Thank you !

Comment: Well, don't you think it might make sense to add your actual rewriting rule set to the question? Because without we have the same issue as you have: _we can't seem to find ..._

Comment: You're right. Here is my rule:

ErrorDocument 404  https://www.mapaetmoi.fr/404.php

Comment: In your question you _now_ state that you have "several redirect rules and also this line" in your configuration file. Yet you _still_ don't add your rewriting rules to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have the solution
I replace ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mapaetmoi.fr/404.php
By ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

And it works !

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the htaccess file to :

DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404  https://www.mapaetmoi.fr/404.php

And the issue is the same.

I wonder if it could not come from the point of the domain name (managed by a provider A) on the hosting (managed by a provider B)? Do you think this could be the case?